# Can't upload images (incorrect "file exceeds upload_max_filesize" error)

Tags: uploads, php.ini

This is my first WordPress site. I've installed it on my Linux Ubuntu 16.04 remote server (which is in my house). I've got a LEMP stack installed on this server. When I try to upload images to my WordPress site, I get an error that says:

> The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

I changed every php.ini file I could find to have upload_max_filesize = 64M. In fact, the upload page for my WordPress site specifically says "Maximum upload file size: 64 MB." So, I know my changes have been implemented. However, no images will upload. Even images < 2 MB.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved this finally!

I had another .conf file in my fpm/pool.d directory that had upload_max_filesize value in it. I was diligently changing the value in this conf file in addition to the php.ini file.

`php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize] = 64M #comment`

I also had what I thought was a comment in the same line. I suspected this was the issue. Removed the #comment. Restarted php and nginx. Voila. I can now upload images!

Thanks for your help, Patel Jignesh!

Answer (score 0):

Use any one option. [More info:](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/)

> 1) wp-config.php

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

> 2) Theme Functions File

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

> 3) Create or Edit an existing PHP.INI file

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

> 4) htaccess Method

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

Comment: I changed 1) from '100M' to '256M'. For 2) I don't know where in the functions file to add the lines you gave (it is a very large file and I have no `@ini_set` lines in it, so not sure where to put them). For 3), I already had those lines in my php.ini file. For 4), doesn't that apply to Apache? I use Nginx. Also want to repeat that the upload file size appears to be correct (as shown in above pic), but my images are declined anyway.

Comment: After edit in PHP.INI file restart the server or not? if not then it please  restart the server. it's necessary.

Comment: Yes, I've restarted the server. I've also restarted the php-fpm service and nginx service after every change. I still get the same error.

Comment: i am search about for other solution but not find anyone. so you Contact of Web Hosting Support and ask to increase file size upload limit.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am the web host, so I need to figure this out. :(